# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() working locally but not remotely

Tags: php, loops, csv

I'm trying to read a .CSV file and print it in a table format in HTML. At the end of the page is a comments text field where comments get submitted and saved in the database.

When I tested the code below locally it works fine. When I tried to run it on the linux server, it prints out fine when first opened, but when I press submit to save a comment, the page refreshes and the table does not print. Giving an "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" error. (Note: this doesn't happen locally, i can submit all I want and it does not return an error.)

I've searched on stackoverflow and it seems that most of these problems are related to declaring the variable as an array. However, it seems odd to me as the code works fine the first time with no error, but once I submit it returns an error.

UPDATE: full code for file posted below.

```
<script>
    window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
        window.opener.location.reload();
    }
</script>

<?php
//---------------------------------Head/BG---------------------------------------
//Request Case ID
$case = "";
if(isset($_REQUEST['case'])) {
$case = $_REQUEST['case'];
}

$patientID = "";
if(isset($_REQUEST['patient'])) {
$patientID = $_REQUEST['patient'];
}


//Include basic functions to allow connection to SQL db.
include("generic.php"); 
//Include css and header information.
$printTitle = "Volume Report for Case ".$case."";
$printHeader = "Volume Report for Case ".$case."";
$printFooter = "";
$printBreadcrumb = "";
include("header.php");

//submit tableStatus update
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
    saveTableStatus($case); 
}
//-----------------------------Start of Content----------------------------------

showStatusComment($case);
printVolumeTable($case,$patientID);
tableStatus($case);


//---------------------------End of Content--------------------------------------
//---------------------------Functions Definitions-------------------------------

//print report.csv Table
function printVolumeTable($case,$patientID){
echo "<html><body><table border='1'>\n\n";
$f = fopen("analyze/".$case."/".$patientID."/report.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";

        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "<tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
}


function showStatusComment($case) {

    $connection = getMySqlConnection();
    $sql = "SELECT p.STATUS_NAME, c.volume_comments FROM cases c, primary_status_lookup as p WHERE c.volume_status=p.STATUS_ID and c.caseid='".$case."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

    if($result!== FALSE){
        while ($record = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
            $status=$record[0];
            $comments=$record[1];

            if($status == 'Clear Status') {$status = 'None'; $comments = 'None';}
            print("<p><b>Table Status: </b>".$status." / <b>Comments: </b>".$comments."</p>");
        }

    }
}

//Status & Comments 
function tableStatus($case) {
    $connection = getMySqlConnection();
    $sql = "SELECT volume_status, volume_comments FROM cases WHERE caseid='".$case."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

    if($result!== FALSE){
        while ($record = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
            $status=$record[0];
            $comments=$record[1];

        print("<form><p>");

        showStatusComment($case);
        statusDropdown($case,$status);
        print("<input type=hidden name='case' value='".$case."'/>");
        print("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label><b>Comments:</b><textarea name='comments' cols=70 rows=2 >".$comments."</textarea></label><br/><br/>");
        print("<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/><INPUT type='button' value='Close Window' onClick='window.close()'></form>");


        }
    }

}


//Status Dropdown
function statusDropdown($case,$status){
    print("<b>Status:</b>");
    $dropdown = "<select name = 'status'><option selected='selected' value=NULL>--Select Status--</option>";

    $connection = getMySqlConnection();
    $sql = "SELECT STATUS_ID, STATUS_NAME FROM primary_status_lookup ORDER BY STATUS_ID ASC"; 
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

    while($record=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

            if ($status == '') {

            $dropdown .= "<option value = '{$record['STATUS_ID']}'> {$record['STATUS_NAME']}</option>";

            } else if (($status == $record['STATUS_ID']) && ($status == '99')) { 

            $dropdown .= "<option value = '{$record['STATUS_ID']}'> {$record['STATUS_NAME']}</option>";

            } else if ($status == $record['STATUS_ID']) { 

            $dropdown .= "<option value = '{$record['STATUS_ID']}' selected='selected'> {$record['STATUS_NAME']}</option>";

            } else {

            $dropdown .= "<option value = '{$record['STATUS_ID']}'> {$record['STATUS_NAME']}</option>";

            }
    }
    $dropdown .="</select>";
    echo $dropdown;

}



function saveTableStatus($case)
{
    //retrieve selected status
    $status = '';
    if(isset($_REQUEST['status'])) {
        $status = $_REQUEST['status'];
    }

    //retrieve typed comments
    if(isset($_REQUEST['comments'])) {
        $comments = $_REQUEST['comments'];
    }

    if($status=='NULL') {
        print("<p class='error'>No status selected, please select a status and try again.</p>");
    }

    else if (($status!=='NULL')){
        $connection = getMySqlConnection();
        mysql_query("START TRANSACTION", $connection);

        if ($status =='99') {$comments = '';}
        $result= mysql_query("Update cases Set volume_status=".$status.", volume_comments ='".mysql_real_escape_string($comments)."' Where caseid='".mysql_real_escape_string($case)."'", $connection);
            if($result) {
                mysql_query("COMMIT", $connection);
                print("<p class='saved'>Table Status Updated!</p>");
            } else {
                mysql_query("ROLLBACK", $connection);
            }
            mysql_close($connection);

        }
}


?>
```

Comment: my guess, is theres something wrong with your file. try echoing out `$line` before the error

Comment: What is the path of this PHP script and what is the path of the PHP script you are submitting to? Are they the same file?

Comment: First of all, you have some strange filename, dots are inside strings and strings are not properly concatenated. Also, debug your `$f=...` and take a look at `$f`, is it opened?

Comment: @beiller They are not in the same path. I have reposted the entire program on here for clarification.

Comment: @aneri I have reposted the entire program on here, $f definitely opens as it works locally, and also the first time opening the page remotely. I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't work when submit.

Comment: @beiller my mistake, i meant to say they are in the same file*

Comment: @Ascherer I fixed that too. it was a typo don't think that's the reason.. as it did ran the first time, and also on my local server. Just trying to figure out why it doesn't run after submit.

Comment: yeah, noticed that, deleted my comment. Like i said, try echoing out `$line` before the foreach

Comment: @Ascherer I get this: "Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\webserver\apache\htdocs\potalaNIB\www\volumeReport.php on line 51
Array"

Comment: by echo, i meant `print_r`... haha. Sorry. I wonder if its working on most of the lines, but its finding a single line that its having an issue with. You could `print_r` until it gets the issue, and then check what the last print_r showed

Comment: actually, `var_dump` would be better, as it'll show a `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you form, and the script that takes the posted form are not on the same path, then your

```
 $f = fopen("analyze/".$case."/".$patientID."/report.csv", "r");
```

will not open the same file.

Edit -

Okay I think your problem is your $case variable. If there is no request, the $case is blank (""). So the above line will open "analyze///report.csv" As you can see depending on this code

```
$case = "";
if(isset($_REQUEST['case'])) {
$case = $_REQUEST['case'];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant that they are on in the same file* it basically recognize through `if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
saveTableStatus($case); }`